# Overloaded constructor with default parametars

Tags: c++

I have two constructors overloaded like this, the problem is that the wrong constructor overload is entered :

```
class Param
{ 
    Param(
     const std::string& name,
     const MyVariant& variant = MyVariant()
     const std::string& desc = std::string(""),
     bool b1 = true,
     bool b2 = true )
     :
     mName(name),
     mValue(variant),
     mDesc(desc),
     mB1(b1),
     mB2(b2) {}

     Param( 
      const std::string& name,
      const MyVariant& variant,
      bool b1)
      :
      mName(name),
      mValue(variant)
      mB1(b1) {}

   private:
      std::string mName;
      MyVariant mValue;
      std::string mDesc;
      bool mB1;
      bool mB2;
};

 Param p("name",4,"desc"); // this enters the second constructor, not the first why ?
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It uses the second constructor because `"desc"` is a `const char*` that can be converted to a `bool` implicitly, so that's what the compiler does. There is no implicit conversion from `const char*` to `std::string`, so the first constructor is not even a candidate here.

To use the first constructor you 'd need to explicitly pass in a `string`:

```
Param p("name",4,std::string("desc"));
```

Comment: Fix it using an enum type for your flags b1 and b2, which also makes calls to the constructor self-documenting.  It is totally unobvious what b1 and b2 are for and also calling Param("name", 4, "desc", true, false) is not obvious but Param("name", 4, "desc", Param::READONLY) would be (assuming this is a function of the flags).

Answer (score 0):

The compiler prefers to convert the type of the string literal, `"desc"`, to a `const char*` and then to a `bool`, rather than invoking the conversion constructor of `std::string`. You can make sure the first constructor is called by doing this:

```
Param p("name",4,std::string("desc"));
```